# Sound Distortion with Flash Player

Tags: audio, adobe-flash

When I play music using any Flash player, whenever there is the tiniest amount of low frequencies, I hear a high pitch ringing noise. It does that on all the highest quality streams I could try such as vimeo or 1080p youtubes.

Example:
http://vimeo.com/dakotalapse/temporaldistortion
I hear a constant ringing sound when notes play, it sounds like a sampling rate frenquency gone wrong.

I tried:

- Reinstalling Flash
- Clearing Flash and browser temporaries
- Reinstalling audio drivers

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what the problem was, it had to do with sampling rate as I suspected.

The sound device was set at 48000Hz and the sources at 44100Hz. I guess the sound device (Realtek) or application resampler implementations are very naive and since both frequencies are so close it produces ringing. 44100Hz worked fine but I changed it to 96000Hz so that I'm also covered if I get to play 48KHz stuff.